# How to uninstall the .net Productivity Power Tools (PPT)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-power-tools

I have recently installed .net Productivity Power Tools and then ReSharper later some time. However most of the futures offered by PPT is being offered by ReSharper as well. Thus I would like uninstall the PPT instead of disabling the futures of PPT using **Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options> Productivity Power Tools**.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Click "Tools/Extension manager" in the menus.

On the left side of the dialogue, select "Installed Extensions" and then "All."

Select "Productivity Power Tools" and click the "Uninstall" button.

Comment: If you used the tabbing features, you might need to reset dead floating views after deinstalling: Window -> Reset Window Layout

Comment: Ditto - that thing was more trouble that it was worth! Glad to be rid of it thanks to this tip.

Comment: Does anyone know why my Productivity Power Tools (both on Visual Studio Professional 2012 AND Visual Studio Community 2013) is disabled and won't get enabled?? Even after uninstalling the installing it.

Comment: What happens when you already did that (aka it doesn't appear anymore on extensions) but it still shows on Visual Studio? Oh God!!!